# Cross Join then left Join (Uknown column)

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, cross-join

What query would I do if this code is working on PHPMyAdmin SQL:

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(d.date, '%b %e %Y') date, 
u.employee_id, ai.time_in, 
ao.time_out 
FROM (SELECT date FROM hris_timein UNION SELECT date FROM hris_timeout order by date asc) d 
CROSS JOIN hris_users u 
LEFT JOIN hris_timein ai ON u.employee_id = ai.employee_id AND ai.date = d.date 
LEFT JOIN hris_timeout ao ON u.employee_id = ao.employee_id AND ao.date = d.date
```

Output: [see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrKvD.png)

But when I use this code in my project, it displays an error:

```
Error description   Unknown column 'd.date' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: Are you certain this error is reproducible using the exact code you pasted above?

Comment: #1. `date` is a keyword. It is strongly recommended to quote it with backticks. #2. ORDER BY applied in the subquery will be lost in outer query - remove it (and add in outer query if needed). #3. I think that SQL code in your project differs from one shown. Check in General Log what code is received by MySQL in practice. Also it is possible that the error is generated not by MySQL but by some client-side pre-parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query looks correct, try it with quoted identifiers.

```
SELECT 
            DATE_FORMAT(d.`date`, '%b %e %Y') `date`, 
            u.`employee_id`,
            ai.`time_in`, 
            ao.`time_out` 
    FROM
           (
               SELECT
                           `date`
                   FROM
                           `hris_timein`
               UNION
               SELECT
                           `date`
                   FROM
                           `hris_timeout`
           ) d 
        CROSS JOIN
           `hris_users` u 
        LEFT JOIN
           `hris_timein` ai
               ON u.`employee_id` = ai.`employee_id` AND ai.`date` = d.`date` 
        LEFT JOIN
           `hris_timeout` ao
               ON u.`employee_id` = ao.`employee_id` AND ao.`date` = d.`date`;
```